# Returning a type based on a constraint, SwiftUI

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I'm looking for a way where I can change a list based on an enum case, where the source for the lists are CaseIterable enums. For example:

```
enum TypeA: Int, CaseIterable {
    case one, two, three
}

enum TypeB: Int, CaseIterable {
    case a, b, c
}
```

I would like to write something like:

```
enum PropChoice {
    case typeA, typeB
  
    func chosenEnumType<T: CaseIterable>() -> T {
        switch self {
            case .typeA:
                return TypeA.self as! T
            case .typeB:
                return TypeB.self as! T
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
let propType = PropChoice.typeA
let choices = propType.chosenEnumType.allCases()  \\\ Compiler error `Generic parameter T could not be inferred`

for choice in choices {
    print(choice.rawValue)
}
```

I'm getting a compiler error as shown above. For interest - the use case for me, is a SwiftUI app, where a user can select a property in a filter screen, and I want to show a list of the options in the Picker.

Comment: Generics isn't really what you need here, since your return type isn't generic, you simply want to be able to return several different types. The solution to this is to return a common type, which is this case would be `CaseIterable` (or more precisely, `CaseIterable && RawRepresentable`, however that cannot be used as a return type due to the `associatedType` requirements of the protocol. So you'd need type erasure to be able to return a type conforming to `CaseIterable`, however, type erasing `Caseiterable` isn't a trivial task (and I'm not sure if it's even possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about building `some View`? Good enough?

```swift
enum PickerSelection {
  case typeA, typeB

  @ViewBuilder var forEach: some View {
    switch self {
    case .typeA:
      forEach(TypeA.self)
    case .typeB:
      forEach(TypeB.self)
    }
  }

  private func forEach<PickerSelection: CaseIterable & Identifiable>(
    _: PickerSelection.Type
  ) -> some DynamicViewContent
  where PickerSelection.AllCases: RandomAccessCollection {
    ForEach(PickerSelection.allCases) {
      Text(verbatim: "\($0)")
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
@State var selection = PickerSelection.typeA


Picker("Picker Selection", selection: $selection) {
  selection.forEach
}
```

```swift
extension Identifiable where Self: CaseIterable {
  var id: Self { self }
}

enum TypeA: Int, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
  case one, two, three
}

enum TypeB: Int, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
  case a, b, c
}
```